# Material Controls for Library Override

Tags: materials, library-overrides

is it possible to create material controls that are useable on a library override object/material without making it local?

E. g. I have a very simple material with just a mix RGB node (see screenshot) and I would like the user to be able to change the FAC value but it is greyed out.

Is that possible at the moment (without slaming a driver onto it and controlling the value with bone translations)?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

### Disclaimer

As of the writing of this, material overrides are not officially supported and the material override does not carry over when the file is saved and re-loaded. However I'll leave the answer as is as I believe this will be the desired workflow to override materials.

Sources :

Library Override project https://developer.blender.org/T73318

Possible workaround ? https://developer.blender.org/T82404#1155236

### Answer

You can use the [Make Library Override Hierarchy](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.html#make-library-override-operator-make-library-override-hierarchy) operator while the material is selected in the outliner to make a material library override.

[image]

Note the arrow that pierces the chain icon in the user interface to symbolize the library override.

Another solution which doesn't involve adding an override on the whole object + data is to add a lib override on only the object at first, then going into the material interface and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Click on the chain icon to add an override.

[image]

Comment: Hm, well, that works too, I suppose. But it seems to reset when I reload the file for some reason despite saving.

Ah, well, have to fiddle around with it, isn't that big of a deal, thanks.

Comment: @Marcus The material library overrides are not yet fully supported. I added a link to the override project fyi in the answer. For now it's just not reliable enough to be used.

Comment: Also https://devtalk.blender.org/t/are-library-overrides-broken/12300

Comment: Ah, sorry, I kinda missed the most obvious part right at the start. I suppose I was distracted by pictures. :(

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No that's alright, I edited my answer after you pointed ou it didn't work ! :p I'm seeing very promising experimental features related to overrides in the latest 3.0 beta version so it may be fixed sooner rather than later

Comment: according to https://developer.blender.org/T82404 this has been fixed.  @mont29

Comment: @james_t ooh nice ! Awesome :)